# Google Auth sign in ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

Tags: swift, xcode, api, cocoa-touch, google-authentication

I am getting an error "ambiguous reference to member 'subscript" on this piece of code. I have no idea what it means as all the fixes I found just give straight answer and haven't explained what they mean and I am also very very new to swift so diving a bit deeper than expected.

Any help? Thanks

```
func application(application: UIApplication,
                     openURL url: NSURL, options: [String: AnyObject]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url as URL!,
                                                    sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String,
                                                    annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify your Xcode/iOS/Swift version.

Here's a working example for iOS 10:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
}
```